# How to enter a different text in same element after clicking in Add button?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Application has **ADD** Button, that need to be clicked after entering **Fname** and **Lname**. Once **ADD** button is clicked, another **Fname** and **Lname** text fields appears. I have tried to use index, but not worked. Text is getting entered in the first text box multiple times.

```
<input class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" matinput="" type="text" autocomplete="on" name="undefined" min="undefined" max="undefined" required="" maxlength="50" id="mat-input-16" placeholder="First Name" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
```

[image]

First time the text is getting entered in the Element.

```
private IWebElement Input_Auto_SomeOneInjuredLname => FindElement(By.Id("mat-input-13"));
Input_Auto_SomeOneInjuredLname.SendKeys(data.Auto_IsSomeoneInjuredLname);
```

Comment: Please enter html of both the elements you are trying to enter values in

Comment: @SameerArora Done Sir

Comment: Can you put your code also ? Because you are saying the value is getting entered multiple time on the same field. Putting the code would help in identifying the issue

Comment: Input_Auto_SomeOneInjuredFname.SendKeys(data.Auto_IsSomeoneInjuredFname);

Comment: Input_Auto_SomeOneInjuredFname1.SendKeys(data.Auto_IsSomeoneInjuredFname1);

Comment: Please Check the Image attached

Comment: Please attach code not screenshots.

Comment: You didn't post the code where you attempt to enter text in the second (or later) boxes. Your code has a single ID which clearly will enter the text in the same box over and over. Please post an [mcve] that includes not only the code you are using that repros the issue but also the HTML for at least two of the fields so we can see how they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find Element by XPath as follows:**

- (//input[@placeholder="Last Name"])[3]
- (//input[@placeholder="First
  Name"])[3]

**Change needs to be done :**

- (//input[@placeholder="First Name"])[**_ADD_INDEX_VARIABLE**]
- (//input[@placeholder="Last Name"])[**_ADD_INDEX_VARIABLE**]

> Increment the value of Index Variable  through **for loop** or **while loop**
>   starting with **value =1**